# Express app inside docker. Restricting access to host localhost only

Tags: node.js, express, docker, nginx

I am trying to restrict access to my express/nodejs app so that it can only be accessed from it's domain url. Currently if I go to `http://ip-address-of-server:3000`, the app gets served directly, bypassing nginx.

I have tried adding 'localhost' in the app.listen --

`app.listen(4000, 'localhost' ,  () => console.log('Server running'));`

but this ends up making the app completely inaccessible. Even through nginx.

The app is running inside a docker container. And nginx is running on the host. I think this might be causing it but don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Is your nginx on the same machine as node.js or on a different ip?

Comment: @MohitMutha Both on same machine but node is running inside a docker container. Nginx is on the host.

Comment: You could firewall all ports other than the one served by nginx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Docker host mode networking for your app since you mentioned that "The app is running inside a docker container. And nginx is running on the host.".

Ref - https://docs.docker.com/network/host/

This way, it will be reachable via nginx on the same network. Your "localhost" settings will start working as usual after launching the container in docker host mode networking.

Comment: Thanks. Haven't tried this yet but looks like this this would do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want to do IP based filtering i.e. you want the node.js program to be accessible only from nginx (localhost or remote) and locally.

There are two ways

- Use express-ipfilter middleware. https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ipfilter to filter requests based on ips
- Let node.js listen to everything but change the iptables on the host to restrict port access to specific ips. Expose the port of the node.js container to the host using -p and close the iptable for that port to the outside world

I prefer the second way as it is more robust and restricts traffic at the network level

Comment: Can't see how the 2nd method would work. Node.js is running inside docker. So that is where I need to control the access?

Comment: With the second method what you would do is let the node.js listen from all addresses but do not expose any port of the node.js container on the host machine (do not do any port mapping). Add a link between node.js and nginx container https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/apps/service-links/. For the nginx container point to the service name of the node.js container. Also expose the port of the nginx to the host that way nginx will be accessible outside

Comment: nginx is running on the host not inside a container. I am aware in that scenario it is possible to just refer to the app without exposing any ports.

Comment: In that case expose the port of the node.js container to the host using -p and close the iptable for that port to the outside world

Comment: Thanks. That sounds like a workable solution. Edit the answer please?